# Add a DataFrame column to group based on another column instances

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I just got started with Pandas and I am struggling to add a simple column that adds the string group + the number occurrences of unique values on a column.

I have tried to use groupby, but I dont know how to add a number based on the column name

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
data['group'] = data.groupby('name') # ???
```

```
   name  color
0  car   white
1  car   black
2  car   red
3  bus   white
4  bus   black
5  bus   red
```

It should look like this

```
   name  color  group
0  car   white  group1
1  car   black  group1
2  car   red    group1
3  bus   white  group2
4  bus   black  group2
5  bus   red    group2
```

Comment: could `name` column have unordered/ungrouped values?

Comment: No they are always strings

Comment: The csv is order by name yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [**`factorize()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) here:

```
df=df.assign(group=(pd.factorize(df.name)[0]+1))
```

---

```
  name  color  group
0  car  white      1
1  car  black      1
2  car    red      1
3  bus  white      2
4  bus  black      2
5  bus    red      2
```

Comment: Not sure which is better, but this could also be `.groupby('name', sort=False).ngroup() + 1`...

Comment: It does work, thanks, but any way to add the string group, I might not even needed but I wonder why I can not concatenate the string group

Comment: @Álvaro `df=df.assign(group='group'+pd.Series(pd.factorize(df.name)[0]+1).astype(str))` will work or you

Comment: @JonClements thanks :) based on my experience I have seen factorize to be faster than groupby.(may be wrong though)

Comment: @anky_91 you're probably right... I think the groupby engine has a bit more overhead than what factorize does as that's more a core numpy thing...

Comment: @Álvaro found another way to add the strings `from numpy.core.defchararray import add` and the next line `df.assign(group=add('group',(pd.factorize(df.name)[0]+1).astype(str)))` should also do it, probably faster. just wanted to share

Comment: @anky_91 why use `df.assign(group=...` instead of `df['group'] = ...`? Is there a difference?

Comment: @politicalscientist no, use whatever works best for you. I am used to use `assign` because it returns a view so if I have to chain another method, I can use in the same line. (I have not tested the performance)

Answer (score 2):

With [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) feature:

```
In [162]: df['group'] = 'group' + (df.groupby('name', sort=False).ngroup()+1).astype(str)

In [163]: df
Out[163]: 
  name  color   group
0  car  white  group1
1  car  black  group1
2  car    red  group1
3  bus  white  group2
4  bus  black  group2
5  bus    red  group2
```

Comment: Or a similar approach: `.groupby('name',sort=False).ngroup().add(1).map('group{}'.format)` - leaves it open for a bit more flexibility re: formatting (and avoids the explicit type conversion), but the `'group' + ...` is no doubt going to do better :)

Comment: @JonClements, ok, let's leave it for current simple case. In there would be a need/demand of a more complex formatting - I would go with your suggestion/advice. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, @RomanPerekhrest going to use the factorize option thou just for the speed as I am dealing with loads of data

Answer (score 0):

I feel the existing answer are over-complicating things here. After all, all you need is to create a mapping between name and group name-

```
group_map = {name: f'group{idx+1}' for idx,name in enumerate(set(data['name']))}

group_map
{'bus': 'group1', 'car': 'group2'}

data['group']=data['name'].map(group_map)
```